# How do I extract Bloodnium from mushrooms?

Tags: let-it-die

Let It Die recently added a Bloodnium economy, and my understanding is I get Bloodnium from ultra-rare mushrooms. I finally got one, but I don't know how to actually get the Bloodnium out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just eat the mushroom to earn the bloodnium. Once you return to the waiting room the bloodnium gets taken and added to the pool like money or splithium.

Obvious in retrospect, but given the rarity of the mushroom I didn't want to accidentally eat it when I actually needed to give it to somebody or refine it somehow.